# SSE connection got closed by browser after receiving first data

Tags: spring, java-8, server-sent-events

I wrote a spring sse application but after receiving the first data from server, the sse emitter connection gets closed. I searched and analysed a lot and got to know it is the browser (in my case firefox) who closes the connection. Thats why I got this log in my application logs

```
org.eclipse.jetty.io.EofException
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint.flush(ChannelEndPoint.java:292)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.WriteFlusher.flush(WriteFlusher.java:429)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.WriteFlusher.write(WriteFlusher.java:322)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractEndPoint.write(AbstractEndPoint.java:372)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection$SendCallback.process(HttpConnection.java:750)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.IteratingCallback.processing(IteratingCallback.java:241)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.IteratingCallback.iterate(IteratingCallback.java:224)



Caused by: java.io.IOException: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.writev0(Native Method)
at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.writev(SocketDispatcher.java:55)
at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(IOUtil.java:148)
at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.write(SocketChannelImpl.java:503)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint.flush(ChannelEndPoint.java:272)
... 29 more
```

and this occurred at line `E1.send(value,MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);` 
I understand that since E1 is closed, hence that line threw that exception, by I could not understand why the browser behaves like this i.e. closing the exisitng connection after getting the first data. I searched a lot in internet for this issue but could not find any solution.

Please help. I am getting stuck with this issue for two weeks. Thanks.

Comment: Why did you re-add the `[sse]` tag?  I don't see anything in the question about x86 SIMD instruction sets or manual vectorization.  See https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sse/info for more about what Stack Overflow's SSE tag is about.  Server-sent events uses `[tag:server-sent-events]`, which this question already has.

Answer (score 0):

I just placed the html page (that contain the javascript code) inside WEB-INF and it worked successfully. Previously I ran it outside of the war file and got the above error. Now it works perfectly.